# Rails Numbers Adding Weirdly (Adding Shipping Rate to Total)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a store set up on my app and in one stage of the checkout process it has to add the shipping rate to the subtotal to get the total (should be simple).  However, when the shipping rate is a single digit (e.g. ($2.00)) it adds correctly like this:

> $32 subtotal + $6 shipping = $38 total

HOWEVER, when the shipping rate is a double digit it adds like this:

> $32 subtotal + $23 shipping = $34 total

From what I can tell it must be something hinky with the place values, but I can't figure out what it is, leading me to believe there's some idiosyncratic Ruby thing I'm doing wrong.

On my ERB view, here is how the form looks:

```
  <% shipping_choices = [] %>
    <% @usps_rates.each do |rate| %>
      <% choice = [] %>
      <% choice << [rate[1], rate[0]] %> <!-- value ( $, desc ) -->
      <% choice << number_to_currency(rate[1]/100, precision: 2).to_s + " - " + rate[0].to_s %> <!-- description -->
      <% shipping_choices << choice %>
    <% end %>
    <%= simple_form_for @order, url: charges_update_order_path(:shipping), method: :post do |f| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-inputs text-left">
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :shipping, shipping_choices, :first, :last, item_wrapper_class: :block_radio_button_collection %>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- form inputs -->
      </div> <!-- choices row -->
      <div class="row">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Continue to Billing", class: "btn btn-manly" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

And this is the `order` model where the information is being saved:

```
def update_order_from_shipping_page(shipping_pair)
  self.shipping = shipping_pair[0]
  self.shipping_choice = shipping_pair[1]
  new_total = self.subtotal + self.shipping
  self.update_attributes(total: new_total, shipping_choice: self.shipping_choice)
end
```

Can anyone see where things are going wrong?

Comment: I see business logic in your view. First thing I noticed.

Comment: @Elyasin, yes, I know this is bad business.  I'm going to move it once I get everything working, but for now I'm going endgame before form.  :/

Comment: Not sure if that is appropriate to say. I would just go endgame now. I'd design proper models, appropriate controllers and *simple* views; this entails that I'd have tests for each and so on.You're likely to solve such issues yourself while testing and developing.
Besides, it is hard (at least) for me to statically analyse Ruby. I could suggest to log the `new_total` - is that the value that is wrong or is it the value that is displayed ?

Comment: Please define "hinky".

Comment: @Elyasin, `new_total` is where the total is calculated, but it's the number for `self.shipping` that is somehow wrong for 2-digit amounts.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, "hinky" is synonymous with funky, suspicious, amuck...

Comment: `self.shipping` is assigned a value of `shipping_pair[0]`. Is that value correct in your opinion ?

Comment: @Elyasin, yes, that's the perplexing part.  `shipping_pair` should be something like `[23.00], ["USPS Priority Mail Express 1-Day"]`...

Comment: I understand the first object *should be* `23`. My question is: Is it indeed `23`? Can you log the value when doing a test for example? Or debug?

Comment: It's in cents, so for the $2 it's 200 and for the $23 it's 2300

Comment: @Elyasin, a sample for `shipping_pair` could be `[2375, "USPS Priority Mail Express 1-Day"]`

Comment: Here's a red flag: `rate[1]/100`. Try a few examples in irb to see what you get ... `200/100`, `210/100`, `290/100`. Also, what is the class returned by `#number_to_currency`?

Comment: @Liz That is not what I asked for. I wanted to ask you if you can test the application and tell us what value you see there. We expect you to do this work if you want us to help you.

Comment: @Elyasin agreed, too many uncertainty with that portion of code, we need to be sure that the expected value, is the value that is being used. Or maybe atleast, show us how `update_order_from_shipping_page` is used. I do believe, for simple addition, there wont be any problem, if the argument is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this line:

```
number_to_currency(rate[1]/100, precision: 2).to_s
```

Needed parentheses around it like this:

```
(number_to_currency(rate[1]/100, precision: 2)).to_s
```

For some reason that did the trick.